# Flutter: How can I update my InkResponse or InkWell string value every time my camera moves?

Tags: flutter, dart

Here's my InkResponse:

```
        new InkResponse(
            child: new Container(
                color: Colors.green,
                child: new Center(
                  child: new Text(
(_lastMapPosition.toString()),
```

My last map position parameters:

```
LatLng _lastMapPosition = _center;

  void _onCameraMove(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
    _currentZoom = cameraPosition.zoom;
    _lastMapPosition = cameraPosition.target;
    print(_lastMapPosition);
  }
```

and my GoogleMap:

```
  SizedBox(
    width:
        MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, // or use fixed size like 200
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
    child: Consumer<ProviderMaps>(builder: (context, Provmap, widget) {
      return GoogleMap(
        myLocationEnabled: true,
        compassEnabled: true,
        mapToolbarEnabled: true,
        zoomControlsEnabled: true,
        zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
        onCameraMove: _onCameraMove,
```

When I change my position by scrolling (camera move), I'm able to print print(_lastMapPosition) rapidly. I want the _lastMapPosition string to be sent to my InkResponse and update every time I scroll. How can I do this?

Comment: Sounds like a job for setState

Comment: Isn't that only for ontapped or onpressed actions? I need this widgets state to constantly update

Comment: You can add a setState call to _onCameraMove. You could also create a stream (with Stream controller) of values and use the StreamBuilder widget to rebuild whatever you want updated each time a new value is introduced to the stream. So you would just .add values to the stream controller in _oncameramove

Comment: Cant make the setState without something like OnPressed or Ontapped...I'll continue searching for something like this

Comment: am dying here: 


            new InkResponse(
                _onCameraMove: (CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
                  setState(() {
                    _lastMapPosition();
                  });
                },
                child: new Container(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    child: new Center(
                        child: new Text(

                      (_lastMapPosition).toString(),

Comment: nevermind I got it... Is it better on resources to use a stream though? or same thing?

Comment: I think just a different approach, if you are concerned about resources you can look more at what widgets are actually rebuilding, or what widgets you know you need to rebuild, and how those are arranged. setState automatically triggers rebuilds in your widget tree where values have changed, but you can be explicit about what you want to rebuild if you the StreamController / StreamBuilder pattern. It is also easier to abstract it into another layer in your code. You can also look into using the bloc pattern / flutter_bloc library. There are lots of different approaches to state management.

Answer (score 0):

```
  void _onCameraMove(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
    _currentZoom = cameraPosition.zoom;
    _lastMapPosition = cameraPosition.target;
    
      setState(() {
        _lastMapPosition;
      });
    print(_lastMapPosition);
  }




    new InkResponse(
        child: new Container(
            color: Colors.grey,
            child: new Center(
                child: new Text(
              (_lastMapPosition).toString(),
            )))),
```